# dlsym Functions inside a class c++ Linux

Tags: c++, linux, dlsym

How I can access a function inside a class using dlsym?

Example:

```
 class test
  {
    public:
    int (testCall)();
  };
```

If I use dlsym(handle, "testCall"); it gives me error 
 Call to dlsym failed : /usr/lib/a.so: undefined symbol: **testCall**

Comment: Is testCall your function? Is it written in C++? Is it a standalone or member function?

Comment: That class method's name is not really "test". See the first answer to the linked duplicate question for the explanation, and how to figure out the real symbol name, which you can use with dlsym().

Comment: Thanks, Solved the problem.